# How can I copy a file from one folder to another folder within a container in Docker?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I already found ways for moving file between host and container but was not able to figure out on how to moves files within same container using YML. Can some one help me on this?

Comment: Can you pls show your `Dockerfile` / 'YML` file? what is your use case?

Comment: It's possible I've grossly misunderstood your question, but you can just use the standard `cp` and `mv` commands to  move files inside a container.  I'm not sure what you mean by `YML`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ssh](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59946/how-to-copy-file-to-another-machine-through-terminal) command. First find IP of each docker container and then ssh into one terminal to transfer file.

```
man scp
The very basic usage:

scp remote_user@remote_host:/path/to/remote/file /path/to/local/file
and vice versa:

scp /path/to/local/file remote_user@remote_host:/path/to/remote/file
```