# Docker: How to copy a file from one folder in a container to another?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to copy my compiled war file to tomcat deployment folder in a Docker container. As `COPY` and `ADD` deals with moving files from host to container, I tried

```
RUN mv /tmp/projects/myproject/target/myproject.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
```

as a modification to the answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41732234/how-can-i-copy-a-file-from-one-folder-to-another-folder-within-a-container-in-do). But I am getting the error

```
mv: cannot stat ΓÇÿ/tmp/projects/myproject/target/myproject.warΓÇÖ: No such file or directory
```

How can I copy from one folder to another in the same container?

Comment: `mv` works fine, that means just that your file (`/tmp/projects/myproject/target/myproject.war`) is not there. Maybe show us how did you put / generate that file there

Comment: I copied the source files to `/tmp/projects/myproject/` and used ant build to generate the .war file. The  .war has to be generated in the container as I need to maintain different environments. Build was successful

Comment: you can try to do `RUN ls /tmp/projects/myproject/target/` before `mv`and see if you really have something there or just `bash` in the container before `mv`

Comment: tried. actually there was a problem with the build. Thanks Edwin!

Answer (score 8):

I feel rather silly posting a new answer six years later, but strangely, to my eyes, the simplest answer to the actual OP is missing. For the next person like myself, here's what I was looking for.

```
#just for grins, I empty the destination folder first
RUN rm ./xyz/pdq/*

#I now copy the file def.pdf into the pdq folder
RUN cp /abc/def.pdf ./xyz/pdq
```

There is mention in the post of mv, but strangely no mention of cp. That is, in fact, the answer to the OP question: "How can I copy from one folder to another in the same container?"

Anyhoo.

Answer (score 5):

You can create a multi-stage build:

https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/

Build the .war file in the first stage and name the stage e.g. build, like that:

```
FROM my-fancy-sdk as build
RUN my-fancy-build #result is your myproject.war
```

Then in the second stage:

```
FROM my-fancy-sdk as build2
COPY --from=build /tmp/projects/myproject/target/myproject.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
```

Comment: The `as build` part is really important... I was getting `pull access denied` errors from the default registry, docker.io for not having a build by that name. What I really needed was `RUN "mv src dest"`

Answer (score 0):

A better solution would be to use volumes to bind individual war files inside docker container as done [here](https://github.com/reactome/container/blob/243fa1af0a7f83cec2bc6c8103507c134d256d24/docker-compose.yml#L22).

### Why your command fails

The command you are running tries to access files which are out of context to for the dockerfile. When you build the image using `docker build .` the daemon sends `context` to the builder and only those files are accessible during the build. In `docker build .` the context is `.`, the current directory. Therefore, it will not be able to access `/tmp/projects/myproject/target/myproject.war`.

### Copying from inside the container

Another option would be to copy while you are inside the container. First use [volumes](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#volume) to mount the local folder inside the container and then go inside the container using `docker exec -it <container_name> bash` and then copy the required files.

### Recommendation

But still, I highly recommend to use

```
docker run -v "/tmp/projects/myproject/target/myproject.war:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/myproject.war" <image_name>
```

Comment: he wanted to copy files inside the container, from one location inside the container to other location inside the container.

Comment: @Edwin I covered that point in my second option. Copying from inside the container