# Move file within Docker image in the build process

Tags: docker

[Docker: How to copy a file from one folder in a container to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46400946/docker-how-to-copy-a-file-from-one-folder-in-a-container-to-another)

Same question basically, but I'd like to move the file within the build process

I'm doing this right now:

```
COPY . /app
RUN mv backend/backend/local_settings.py.default backend/backend/local_settings.py
```

This is not working, though. It is corrupting the file system somehow. When I go to the folder this is what it happens when I type `ls`

```
bash-4.4# ls -liah
ls: ./local_settings.py.default: No such file or directory
total 28
555172697 drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          24 Mar  6 15:37 .
582753791 drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          65 Dec 11 16:57 ..
580798835 -rw-r--r--    1 root     root           0 Oct  3 20:27 __init__.py
580798836 drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          42 Mar  6 15:35 __pycache__
580798844 -rw-r--r--    1 root     root        3.7K Dec 11 16:57 settings.py
555172698 -rw-r--r--    1 root     root        2.8K Feb  8 19:11 local_settings.py
580798847 -rw-r--r--    1 root     root        3.6K Dec 11 16:57 urls.py
580798848 -rw-r--r--    1 root     root         392 Oct  3 20:27 wsgi.py
```

If I type `vim backend/` and tap TAB for autocompletion the file shows there!

```
bash-4.4# vim backend/
__init__.py                settings.py                local_settings.py.default  wsgi.py                    
__pycache__/               local_settings.py          urls.py
```

On top of that, when I run my command with `docker run` I get the error:

The settings file import the local_settings.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
05-Mar-2019 16:20:10      File "/app/backend/backend/settings.py", line 139, in <module>
05-Mar-2019 16:20:10        from .local_settings import *
05-Mar-2019 16:20:10    ImportError: No module named 'backend.local_settings'
```

The file is there, but it is not being recognized! When I go to the container in interactive mode, the command works.

---

EDIT
Docker info

```
Server Version: 18.09.2
Storage Driver: overlay2
 Backing Filesystem: xfs
 Supports d_type: false
 Native Overlay Diff: true
Kernel Version: 3.10.0-957.5.1.el7.x86_64
```

Stat on local_settings files

```
bash-4.4# stat local_settings.py.default
stat: can't stat 'local_settings.py.default': No such file or directory
bash-4.4# stat local_settings.py
  File: local_settings.py
  Size: 2816        Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 2fh/47d Inode: 555172698   Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2019-03-05 20:17:27.000000000
Modify: 2019-02-08 19:11:12.000000000
Change: 2019-03-05 19:37:35.000000000
```

Comment: Are you sure that's the import Error? Isn't backend a folder? do a `ls -liah` and see if the file is executable or not. Maybe changing the file name also changes the permission to default. After moving the file do a `chmod +x` on the file and test it again

Comment: Yes, that's the error. I will add more info

Comment: What's your entrypoint?

Comment: Please provide the output of `docker info` command (at least information regarding storage driver, backing FS, and the kernel version).

Comment: Also, could you try running `stat local_settings.py.default` and `stat local_settings.py` inside the container?

Comment: Krishna there is no entrypoint. Danila Kiver, I added the info you asked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `overlay2` storage driver with backing file system which does not support `d_type`. This makes `overlay2` [pretty mad in its behavior](https://linuxer.pro/2017/03/what-is-d_type-and-why-docker-overlayfs-need-it/). According to [official Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/overlayfs-driver/), such configuration is simply not supported because of issues like this:

> The following backing filesystems are supported:
>
> ...
>
> `xfs` (RHEL 7.2 and higher), but only with `d_type=true` enabled.

There also should be a warning about this misconfiguration in the log of your Docker daemon.

You have to [recreate the backing file system](https://linuxer.pro/2017/03/what-is-d_type-and-why-docker-overlayfs-need-it/#how-to-solve-the-problem), making it either `ext4` or `xfs` with `d_type` support.

Comment: I couldn't find any warning in my docker daemon log. I did `sudo cat /var/log/messages  | grep docker | grep warning` and no messages were found

Comment: Try grepping `overlay2`instead. The message should look like `overlay2: the backing xfs filesystem is formatted without d_type support, which leads to incorrect behavior. Reformat the filesystem with ftype=1 to enable d_type support. Running without d_type support will no longer be supported in Docker 1.16.` (and probably may vary across Docker versions).

Comment: I was checking on the default /var/log/messages, but this happened a week ago. I checked in the rolled log and it was there. Thank you a lot, @Danila Kiver!

Comment: Also, if you do a `docker info` it shows this warning at the very end. Just noticed that now